# MySQL select query for date range with same time

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, timestamp

TABLE

EventID --- EventTime (`TIMESTAMP`)

```
1   2013-09-29 12:00:00.0
2   2013-09-29 12:01:00.0
3   2013-09-29 12:03:00.0
4   2013-09-28 1:03:00.0
5   2013-09-27 23:03:00.0
6   2013-09-26 17:03:00.0
7   2013-09-25 12:01:00.0
8   2013-09-24 20:03:00.0
9   2013-09-23 5:03:00.0
10  2013-09-23 12:01:00.0
```

I want to retrieve rows, in MySQL, which satisfy given date range with **same time**.

So, if I query to retrieve rows with '2013-09-**26 12:01**' as EventTime value for +/- 5 days, I expect to get 2nd, 7th and 10th rows.

Please help frame SQL statement. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I had missed a scenario which is bit involved. Please take a look a this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078801/mysql-select-query-for-date-range-with-time-range/, and request to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE EventTime >= '2013-09-26 12:01' - INTERVAL 5 DAY
  AND EventTime <= '2013-09-26 12:01' + INTERVAL 5 DAY
  AND TIME(EventTime) = TIME('2013-09-26 12:01')
```

Comment: As mentioned in comment of OP, I humbly request your help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mysql *HOUR* and *MINUTE* functions

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

That does exactly what you try to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE 
HOUR(EventTime)=HOUR('2013-09-26 12:01') AND 
MINUTE(EventTime)=MINUTE('2013-09-26 12:01') AND 
EventTime BETWEEN 
   DATE_SUB('2013-09-26 12:01', INTERVAL 5 day) AND 
   DATE_SUB('2013-09-26 12:01', INTERVAL -5 day)
```